# Detrended data and ARIMA modeling

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, trend, differencing

What data should I use in ARIMA modeling when I do detrending, is it the original data or the detrended one? Then, what is the d component of the ARIMA model, is it d=0 or d=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use differencing for removing stochastic trends (unit roots), not deterministic trends (linear, polynomial, seasonal or otherwise); beware of overdifferencing (see e.g. Bob Nau ["Identifying the order of differencing in an ARIMA model"](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim2.htm).

Other than that, ARIMA will fit your time series equally well (or equally poorly), just the $d$ parameter will be different depending on whether you pre-difference or not.

Comment: But the detrended data is also a time series, right? Do you mean I can't use ARIMA on this data? By the way, I used detrending since the original time series data is stationary with a trend.

Comment: @DodongKim, I am not sure what you mean by *detrending*. Do you adjust for a deterministic trend by fitting a linear, polynomial or another time trend and obtain the residuals to be used for further analysis with ARIMA? Or do you difference the data and want to apply ARIMA on the differences?

Comment: I used the adfTest (an R function) to test for the stationarity of the original data. The result shows that the data is stationary along with a linear trend.

Comment: Yeah. I used the residuals to be used for further analysis. Is this ok?

Comment: @DodongKim, what residuals did you use? I have listed two options, was it one of them?

Comment: This ,"adjust for a deterministic trend by fitting a linear and obtain the residuals to be used for further analysis with ARIMA".

Comment: @DodongKim, then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But may I ask of some pieces of evidence like research or something. I am looking in the internet about this but I cannot find something. So, I can put it on my RRL. Thanks again for your time, sir.

Comment: @DodongKim, one reference is already linked to in my answer. The rest is typical material of a time series textbook. Hamilton ["Time Series Analysis"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis) (1994) would be a representative example, but there are dozens more.